# How to get response value from API in action.js using React

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native

I've read many examples about this and got no result for my problem, I want to get the values inside MySQL database by using localhost, code with PHP and return the value as JSON format e.g.

```
[
    {"id":"7",
     "name":"Sammy",
     "address":"New York",
     "age":"42"}
]
```

with this format, I can fetch the data by using this code in GetApi.js

```
class GetApi {
 static getAllUsers() {

return fetch('http://192.168.1.199/App/show_all_data.php')
        .then((response) => {
            if (!response.ok) {
                throw Error(response.statusText);
            }

            dispatch(itemsIsLoading(false));

            return response;
        })
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((items) => dispatch(itemsFetchDataSuccess(items)))
        .catch(() => dispatch(itemsHasErrored(true)));
  }
}

export default GetApi;
```

here's the action.js

```
import GetApi from '../../api/GetApi';

export function itemsHasErrored(bool: boolean) {
  return {
    type: "ITEMS_HAS_ERRORED",
    hasErrored: bool
  };
}
export function itemsIsLoading(bool: boolean) {
  return {
    type: "ITEMS_IS_LOADING",
    isLoading: bool
  };
}
export function itemsFetchDataSuccess(items: Object) {
  return {
    type: "ITEMS_FETCH_DATA_SUCCESS",
    items
  };
}
export function itemsFetchData(url: any) {
  return function(dispatch) {
    return GetApi.getAllUsers().then(items => {
    dispatch(itemsFetchDataSuccess(items));
    dispatch(itemsIsLoading(false));
   }).catch(error => {
  throw(error);
    });
  };
}
```

here's the reducer.js

```
const initialState = {
  isLoading: true,
  hasErrored: false,
  items: []
};
export default function(state: any = initialState, action: Function) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "ITEMS_HAS_ERRORED":
      return { ...state, hasErrored: action.hasErrored };
    case "ITEMS_IS_LOADING":
      return { ...state, isLoading: action.isLoading };
    case "ITEMS_FETCH_DATA_SUCCESS":
      return { ...state, items: action.items };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

called action.js function in index.js

```
import { itemsFetchData } from "../../actions";
...
all codings that were not related with calling action.js
...
const navigation = this.props.navigation;
  let items = this.props.items;
  if (items.hasOwnProperty('item')) {
    items = items.item
  }
  return (
    <List
            dataArray={this.props.items}
            renderRow={(
              data 
            ) =>
              <ListItem icon style={styles.listitem}>
                <Left>
                <Text>
                  {data.name}
                  </Text>

                </Left>

                <Right>
                  <Text>
                    {data.address}
                  </Text>
                </Right>
              </ListItem>}
          />
  );

  function bindAction(dispatch) {
   return {
  fetchData: url => dispatch(itemsFetchData(url))
  };
 }
  const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  items: state.homeReducer.items,
  hasErrored: state.homeReducer.hasErrored,
  isLoading: state.homeReducer.isLoading
 });
 export default connect(mapStateToProps, bindAction)(ShowData);
```

I got no results when I'm running the code, it's just showed the loading icon. even when I set isLoading:false, the home menu showed up without the data

I'm just trying to minimize the code inside index.js because it's too long to post that here. I will do that if necessary in the next comment.

Comment: check console, i think there is some error related to `dispatch`, because  with current code `dispatch` will not be accessible inside `getAllUsers` method in GetApi class.

Comment: thanks for the fast response, and yeah it would be great if there's an error showed up but it didn't. just "Finished building javascript bundle in ....ms" maybe i have to put an error code when dispatching?

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using epics , below is an example link for you to follow.

[Epic Example](https://github.com/DanishDeveloper360/MerchantManagementApp/blob/master/src/store/merchants/epics.js)

You can look at the actions and data ajax calls from epic and how it connects back to the action.

Note: Axios is been used here instead of fetch api...

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, somehow i need to make a code only with fetch method. i will learn axios code in the future.